# ArrayAdapter TextView ressource not identical to the original Android default

Tags: java, android, android-layout, spinner

I'm changing the entries of a `Spinner` dynamically inside the java code using `ArrayAdapter`:

```
String[] spec = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.home_specialty_spinner_sem_1_4);
ArrayList<String> specialty = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(spec));
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Launch.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, specialty);
homeSpecialty.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

The problem is that when using the `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` the spinner will look like figure 2 and 3.

[image]

What I want to achieve is getting the look of figure 1 (`android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`) with the dialog style of figure 3 (which is the default I got when populating the `Spinner` with an array of strings using XML (Spinner Entries) without any `ArrayAdapter`)

Any thoughts?

Comment: try this http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2012/12/spinner.html

Comment: figure 1 looks come in a new version API so change the api target of new one